# Call a List populated from AsyncTask doInBackground() in onPostExecute()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have been experimenting with code I found online that allows an xml file to be parsed.
The different parsed fields are shown in the logcat.

The parsing is done in an AsyncTask in doInBackground() resulting in the creation of a list is created, that is used to show the fields for a particular url and that was displayed correctly in logcat.

What I would like to do now is to check if I can show the fields during post-execution.
So I moved the commented out code block that allow the logcat display from doinBackground() to onPostExecute().

When I compile my code, I get an error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

How can I fix this? Is there something fundamental I am missing?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = "MainActivity.java";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
     // parse our XML
     new parseXmlAsync().execute();
      } catch (NullPointerException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      }
      }

      private class parseXmlAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

      try {

      // initialize our input source variable
      InputSource inputSource = null;

      // XML from URL
      URL url = new URL(
      "http://feeds.news24.com/articles/fin24/Tech/rss");
      inputSource = new InputSource(url.openStream());

      // instantiate SAX parser
      SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory
     .newInstance();
      SAXParser saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();

      // get the XML reader
      XMLReader xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader();

       // prepare and set the XML content or data handler before
       // parsing
       XmlContentHandler xmlContentHandler = new XmlContentHandler();
       xmlReader.setContentHandler(xmlContentHandler)

       // parse the XML input source
       xmlReader.parse(inputSource);

       // put the parsed data to a List
       List<ParsedDataSet> parsedDataSet = xmlContentHandler.getParsedData();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
        return null;
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(List<ParsedDataSet> parsedDataSet) {

            // use an iterator so we can loop through the data
            Iterator<ParsedDataSet> i = parsedDataSet.iterator();
            ParsedDataSet dataItem;

            while (i.hasNext()) {

                dataItem = (ParsedDataSet) i.next();

                    /*
                     * parentTag can also represent the main type of data
                     */
                String parentTag = dataItem.getParentTag();
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "parentTag: " + parentTag);

                if (parentTag.equals("item")) {
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Title: " + dataItem.getTitle());
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Description: " + dataItem.getDescription());
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "URL: " + dataItem.getLink());
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
parseXmlAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
```

This means you have a `<Params, Progress, Result>` of `<String, String, String>`.

1) You have no `Progress`. That can be `Void`.

2) You seem not to care about `Params`, or `String... strings`. So that also can be `Void`.

3) If you want `onPostExecute(List<ParsedDataSet> parsedDataSet)` to work, then you need to make `Result` to be `List<ParsedDataSet>`.

The returned value from `doInBackground` to given to `onPostExecute`. You are only returning `null`, and so even if this did work, `parsedDataSet.iterator();` would throw a NullPointerException.

---

Now, to fix the error, it is wanting you to implement

```
onPostExecute(String result)
```

but, instead, you should use

```
ParseXmlAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<ParsedDataSet>>
```

and

```
public List<ParsedDataSet> doInBackground(Void... params)
```

and, then, `return parsedDataSet` from `doInBackground`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I tried your suggestion and it worked. I also the method 1 mentioned by K  Neeraj Lal which also  worked as I am trying to understand this so I don't repeat the mistake again.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error because your AsyncTask signature is `AsyncTask<String, String, String>` and the `onPostExecute` method siignature is `onPostExecute(List<ParsedDataSet> parsedDataSet)` instead of `onPostExecute(String response)`.

You have 2 methods to do this,

**Method 1**

Make `parsedDataSet` global in the `parseXmlAsync`.

```
private class parseXmlAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    List<ParsedDataSet> parsedDataSet;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        ...
        parsedDataSet = xmlContentHandler.getParsedData();
        ...
    }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

        Iterator<ParsedDataSet> i = parsedDataSet.iterator();
        ...
     }
}
```

**Method 2**

Change the signature of the `AsyncTask`

```
private class parseXmlAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<ParsedDataSet>> {
    List<ParsedDataSet> parsedDataSet;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        ...
        parsedDataSet = xmlContentHandler.getParsedData();
        return parsedDataSet;
        ...
    }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(List<ParsedDataSet> parsedDataSet) {

        Iterator<ParsedDataSet> i = parsedDataSet.iterator();
        ...
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I tried method 1 and this worked. I also tried method 2 as well which is fine.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

*Problem is you made mistake in AysncTask. See my below code.*

```
   private class parseXmlAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<ParsedDataSet>> 
{

    @Override
    protected List<ParsedDataSet> doInBackground(String... strings) 
    {
        try {

            // initialize our input source variable
            InputSource inputSource = null;

            // XML from URL
            URL url = new URL("http://feeds.news24.com/articles/fin24/Tech/rss");
            inputSource = new InputSource(url.openStream());

            // instantiate SAX parser
            SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory
                    .newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();

            // get the XML reader
            XMLReader xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader();

            // prepare and set the XML content or data handler before
            // parsing
            XmlContentHandler xmlContentHandler = new XmlContentHandler();
            xmlReader.setContentHandler(xmlContentHandler);
            xmlReader.parse(inputSource);
            List parsedDataSet = xmlContentHandler.getParsedData();

            return parsedDataSet;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<ParsedDataSet> parsedDataSet) {

        // use an iterator so we can loop through the data
        Iterator<ParsedDataSet> i = parsedDataSet.iterator();
        ParsedDataSet dataItem;

        while (i.hasNext()) {

            dataItem = (ParsedDataSet) i.next();

            /*
             * parentTag can also represent the main type of data
             */
            String parentTag = dataItem.getParentTag();
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "parentTag: " + parentTag);

            if (parentTag.equals("item")) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Title: " + dataItem.getTitle());
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Description: " + dataItem.getDescription());
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "URL: " + dataItem.getLink());
            }

        }


    }
}
```